# How to fail a Bazel build on a rule failure?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-rules-nodejs

I am using Bazel rules in NodeJS in my application. The aim is to simply lint a set of files and fail the build if linting fails. What I'm currently experiencing is that the build is successful despite lint errors.

Here's a part of my `BUILD` file:

```
load("@npm//htmlhint:index.bzl", "htmlhint")

filegroup(
    name = "htmldata",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.html"]),
)

htmlhint(
  name = "compile",
  data = [
      "htmlhint.conf",
      "//:htmldata"
  ],
  args = [
      "--config",
      "htmlhint.conf",
      "$(locations //:htmldata)"
  ]
)
```

I first load the hinting library, then I define a filegroup for all the HTML files that I want to lint. Afterward, I use the rule with its data and arguments.

To run the build, I use the default option via npm script: `bazel build //...`

Comment: `BUILD` file looks good. I am not sure about that `htmlhint` package, maybe `htmlhint-cli` will work fine.

Comment: @Slay The `htmlhint-cli` package was last updated 6 years ago and its source code isn't available either. Don't want to risk there given the vulnerabilities rising out of outdated code

Answer (score 1):

Your build file is working as expected. Unfortunately it doesn't do what you want, because when you load the macro from `@npm//htmlhint:index.bzl` it sets up the nodejs binary which is a runnable target, which means that it will only create runfiles + executable when building. In this case, the build will not run the library.

There are several options to do what you want:

1. Use the `htmlhint_test` macro to create a test target.
2. Create a custom rule that will use the nodejs binary to build some artefacts. In this case, you can force the build to fail.

However, I suggest using the first approach, because if `htmlhint` is a linting tool, it won't produce any meaningful outputs and is best to keep it as part of the test suite.

Here's what you need to do to set up the `compile` target as a test target

```
diff --git a/BUILD.bazel b/BUILD.bazel
index 4e58ac5..3db5dbb 100644
--- a/BUILD.bazel
+++ b/BUILD.bazel
@@ -1,11 +1,11 @@
-load("@npm//htmlhint:index.bzl", "htmlhint")
+load("@npm//htmlhint:index.bzl", "htmlhint_test")
 
 filegroup(
     name = "htmldata",
     srcs = glob(["**/*.html"]),
 )
 
-htmlhint(
+htmlhint_test(
   name = "compile",
   data = [
       "htmlhint.conf",
```

Then you can check it with `bazel test //...`.

If you want to see the output just run your `compile` target with `bazel run //path/to:compile`